# can't tab in SelectBoxIt

Tags: javascript, tabindex

Hello my name is Shane,

I am coding a custom website. I have built a contact form and am using SelectBoxIt (http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) for my drop-down feature. I have several Input Fields, two buttons and one Select Box (drop-down). I have the form working perfectly, my issue is with the TabIndex. I have the correct tabindexs coded in each Input, but when I tab to the Select Box it gets ignored.

Here is the page: http://www.lightupco.com/contact.htm
NOTE: you have to click the Envelope/Pen icon to reveal the form.

The only clue I have from researching a forum with similar issue, is it has something to do with the underlying UL throws the tab index off.

I'm not sure what code from my page to include here, to get help figuring this out?

Comment: I just changed to tab index to 2 and it worked.

Comment: The tabindex does work, also for your selectbox. I tried it into IE8, FF3.6.28, Safari.

Comment: @Saul, the tabindex for the SelectBox is already 2?

Comment: @reporter, This works for you? I've tried it in IE9, Chrome & Firefox..?

Comment: Also in Chrome. The order was just strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Shane I wrote SelectBoxIt.  The reason your select box tabindex is getting ignored is because SelectBoxIt hides the original select box and replaces it with new HTML that is easier to style (a div element).  Hence, the tabindex attribute is not being set on the visible drop down (the div element), only the hidden select box.

If you don't mind creating an issue on [Github](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues), I would be happy to add a feature to SelectBoxIt that copies any tabindex attribute on the original select box to the new visible drop down.  That should solve your issues.

Comment: yes!! Thank you Greg, I will try that. Nice job BTW on the SelectBoxit :)

Comment: The feature has now been added:  https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

The selectbox has index 0. If you click in the Name: input, your index is 1, so, your indexes as wrong.

Why using tabindex, after all? -.-

Comment: thanx for replay Saul. I am using Tabindex because my client wants to be able to tab through all the fields in logical order, of course. I tried changing the Select Box to tabindex 0 (as you suggested) and changing the Name Input to "-1" and the rest in the correct order. Trying that - It DID tab me from Name Input to the SelectBox correctly, but it won't tab to anything after that. So it doesn't fix it to give SelectBox an index of "0".. unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: You are already using javascript to build (or manage) the form, is there any plugin or javascript library that could help you?

Comment: Thank you for reply Saul. I figured out a work around. First I removed all Tabindex from form elements, then added Tabindex="-1" to the 2 form buttons, which takes them out of the tab sequence entirely. This way things tab in logical order, the only downfall is you can't tab to the 'Send' button after the Address Field, but this seems fine. ;)  www.lightupco.com/contact.htm